# How to setup environment for windows azure programming

Tags: azure, installation

My systems has VS2013 web express installed. To install windows Azure SDK it ask to install VS update 3 first. Size of VS update 3 ISO file is 5GB+. My net connection is slow so i can't download 5GB in one go. Please guide me if there is any alternative way to set environment for windows azure programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Visual Studio Community 2013](http://www.visualstudio.com/news/vs2013-community-vs), it's got everything you need to get a development environment set up quickly to build apps with the latest .NET Azure SDK v2.5.

Comment: Thanks Christ. Community edition looks good. But this is fresh installation i mean first you have to unstall existing VS then install VS Community 2013 freshly and will be required minimum 1 hr. I think Microsoft should provide a simpler way if someone want to do Azure programming using existing VS already installed.

Comment: In that case you might want to try installing one of the older versions of the .NET Azure SDK that doesn't require you to update your existing VS installation.